# Google LanguageApp different translation from manual translation

Tags: google-apps-script, translate

Has anyone compared the LanguageApp in Apps Script with a manual translation? I have been fighting all day thinking it was surrounding HTML code causing the problem but finally I just plugged plain text into the LanguageApp:

```
function test(){
  Logger.log(LanguageApp.translate(" L’Afrique sera-t-elle écrasée par le poids de sa dette envers la Chine ?", 'fr', 'en')); 
}
```

This comes out in English like a monkey made the translation:

"The Does Africa will be crushed by the weight of its debt to China?"

If I go to the webpage (http://www.lemonde.fr/afrique/article/2017/06/19/l-afrique-sera-t-elle-ecrasee-par-le-poids-de-sa-dette-envers-la-chine_5147440_3212.html) and translate it using the toolbar I get a superb result:

"Will Africa be crushed by the weight of its debt to China?"

Are there 2 versions of translate? One for Google and a substandard one for Apps Script users?